# composer-vendor-folder-shows-up-instead-of-vendor-page-on-vendor-routes

Tags: laravel, routes, package, vendor

I have a vendor routes in my routes folder

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'vendor', 'middleware' => ['auth:vendor']], function () {
      Route::get('/dashboard', 'Vendor\VendorController@dashboard')->name('vendor.dashboard')- 
    >middleware('bannedVendor');

      Route::get('/logout/{id?}', 'Vendor\LoginController@logout')->name('vendor.logout');
 });
```

And whenever i try accessing any vendor routes on my browser my package(vendor) folder shows up instead.
[image]
How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: What server are you using? Apache or Nginx? And what is the base file that the server is pointed to?

Comment: I am making use of apache, WAMP server to be precise on my localhost.